# UITabBarController to UIViewController with inner UITableView

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, storyboard

I apologize in advance for being a total noob with this question, but at least I'm trying right?

Here's my current setup. I have a storyboard setup with the following

UITabBarController -> UIViewController -> TableView -> Cell

I have a Class that is of type UITableViewController setup to feed some static data to the TableView. What I'm getting hung up on is how I can hook up the first view of the UITabBarController to point to the UIViewController that then pulls in the data of the TableViews and it's sells.

Here is the tutorial I've been following. My code is basically the same except my storyboard is different(my way is explained above).
http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-customize-uitableview-storyboard/

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong or need to do in order to hook this up correct?! All help is greatly appreciated!!!

Comment: We can't tell what you're doing wrong without seeing your code, and you telling us what's not working.

Answer (score 1):

Create the following view hierarchy

UITabBarController - > UINavigationController - > UITableviewcontroller -> UIViewController

create tabbar as rootview for application then create navigation controller with tableview as topviewcontroller for that navigationController and then add that navigation controller as view to the tabbar. now to load data in view on selection of cell in tabview use

didSelectRowAtIndexPath method of tableview controller  to call view using push segue with data which you want to show on that view.

// Try this one it will work.